# Using the same route for different types of users in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

My application will have **doctors, patients and administrators**

Now I would like to have the same route for all roles. as following:

```
app.com/dashboard/
app.com/dashboard/appointments
```

But I would like to have a different Controller for the one used for patients, and the one for doctors offcourse. I have tried the following without success

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'dashboard', 'middleware' => ['auth']], function () {

/* Doctor */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:doctor']], function() {
    Route::get('/appointments', 'Doctor\AppointmentController@index');
});

/* Patient */
Route::group(['middleware' => ['role:patient']], function() {
    Route::get('/appointments', 'Patient\AppointmentController@index');
});
```

});

I get an 403 (Unauthorized) error caused by my Role middleware. Even without that I think it's just overwriting the other?

> Has anyone been able to use the same route (/dashboard) for completely different purposed? aka different controllers/views

Thank you!

Comment: I'm not 100 % sure so I don't want to add it as an answer, but I think the easiest and arguably most readable solution would be to create a general middleware that accepts either role, and a general AppointmentController that only has the purpose of directing to the correct controller depending on the role of the current user.

Comment: A Controller redirecting to another one doesn't seem completely good but your answer makes sense! Strange that it's so difficult to achieve

Comment: I'd argue with that @Notflip. It's not great to be redirecting controller methods to each other back and forth all over the place sure. In this case though it might actually be pretty nice to have a single dashboard controller which delegates/proxies out to each totally separate controller depending on the role. I think thats what I'd do in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a workaround for this by checking the user role and then call the controller function accordingly as:

```
Route::get('appointment', function()
{
    if (auth()->user()->isDoctor())
    {
        app()->call('Doctor\AppointmentController@index')
    }
    elseif(auth()->user()->isPatient())
    {
        app()->call('Patient\AppointmentController@index')
    }
});
```